# How can I set the default layout export resolution in pyQgis?

Tags: qgis-3, print-composer, pyqgis-3

I want to change the default export resolution (default value = 300 dpi) programatically when I open the layout designer

```
l = QgsPrintLayout(project)
l.initializeDefaults()
l.setUnits(QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters)
l.setName('my_layout')
self.iface.openLayoutDesigner(l)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following to achieve what you want

```py
project = QgsProject.instance()
manager = project.layoutManager()
layout = manager.layoutByName('layout1') # It's an existing layout we search by name

layout.renderContext().setDpi(250)
iface.openLayoutDesigner(layout)
```